# Music samples for market research surveys

Tags: licensing, fair-use, music, research

Would using short clips (8-15 seconds) of songs embedded in online surveys for market research fall under fair use? If not, what type of music license would be required for this application?

The content of the clips will not be altered, and this research would be for-profit.

Would purchasing the works from iTunes or similar distributor satisfy licensing requirements for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would using short clips (8-15 seconds) of songs embedded in online surveys for market research fall under fair use?

No

> If not, what type of music license would be required for this application?

A public performance licence: see https://www.easysonglicensing.com/pages/help/articles/licensing-music/music-licensing-for-public-performance.aspx

> Would purchasing the works from iTunes or similar distributor satisfy licensing requirements for this application?

No, the licence you buy there is for private use only.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and informative response. If I pay public performance licensing fees to ASCAP, BMI, and SESAC, what is the correct way to obtain music files that are covered by these PROs? Will licensing companies provide them, or do I embed my own copy of the song?